# How to loop through an array and put it into an object

Tags: java, arrays, object

i want to loop through an array i have and assign each value to a variable in an object

sorry i want to make this more clear.

I am reading from a .txt file and need to insert the values for 5 students into objects.

the text file is a a .csv like so

> 1,Frank,West,98,95,87,78,77,80
>
> 2,Dianne,Greene,78,94,88,87,95,92
>
> 3,Doug,Lei,78,94,88,87,95,92
>
> 4,James,Hewlett,69,92,74,77,89,91
>
> 5,Aroha,Wright,97,92,87,83,82,92`

ideally i want to create a loop the iterates though each field and makes a new student object.

the code snippet is the example code i have been given but i can't make it work after hours of trying.

essentially i guess i am asking how the addstudent method should work as that this the method that will take those values and put them into an object.

Code for the readFile() method:

```
/**
* Reads a text file containing student data and uses this to populate the student objects
*
* @param filename Path to the student data file to be read
* @return Whether the file was read successfully
*/
public static boolean readFile(String filename) { 
      File file = new File(filename);
      try {
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
           while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
               String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
               addStudent(id,firstName,lastName,mathMark1,.....); // TODO: Finish adding the parameters
             }
          scanner.close();
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
             System.out.println("Failed to read file");
       } 

    return true;
}
```

Data for studentdata.txt

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You want to create student object(s) from words that your getting from file. Is my assumption correct? @NicholasK

Comment: `public static addStudent(String[] values) {}` then you create a new Student object in the method and assign the values in the array to the Student object.

Comment: @NicholasK yes thats correct, sorry i didn't expect this to get answered so quick, i edited it above to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: How is your `Student` class set up? You're reading the file correctly, all that is required now is to create an object of `Student` (which you have not shared). Also do you want to store all these objects in some collection?

Comment: @NicholasK that is exactly it, sorry i haven't shared my student object but yes i have a class named student, what i need to do is first name a new student object out of each line in the studentdata.txt and then put these objects together in an ADT of some type. the addstudent method will be responsible for this but i am unsure how the code for addstudent should even look.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the text file is set up such that it matches the parameters in your `addStudent(..)` method then you can pass the arguments by using

```
addStudent(words[0], words[1], words[2], ...);
```

Comment: the problem here being that words[0] returns
`1
2
3
4
5
`

Comment: how is the text file set up? what does a line look like?

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear .. according to your coding style i think you try to read data from a text file and store all data into a collection object....

according to my assumption you can do this by using flowing code...

```
public class Student {

    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Student(){}

    //all args constructor 
    public Student(String id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // all getter and setter code
}
```

inside your code change as

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
 while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
               String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
               list.add(new Student(words[0],words[1],words[2])); // TODO: Finish adding the parameters
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a class **Student**.

```
public class Student {
  public String id, first_name,last_name;
  //assuming it was subject grades
  public String[] subject_grades;

  public void Student(String id,String first_name,String last_name,String subject_grades[]){
     this.id = id;
     this.first_name = first_name;
     this.last_name = last_name;
     this.subject_grades = subject_grades;


  }
}
```

then on your **main** method

```
List<Student> student_list = new ArrayList<>();
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
   String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
   student_list.add(new Student(words[0],words[1],words[2], new String[] {words[3],words[4],words[5],words[6],words[7]} ));
}
```